# Shading works for mirrored object only

Tags: materials, modifiers, shaders, mirror

I have mirrored the right eyeball and went to Shading. But what i do there only applies to the left eye. I've made a material and selected it and assigned it but nothing seems to happen.

[image]

I thought i could apply mirror, separate and delete the right eye and mirror the left eye so the shading would apply there too, but when i apply the mirror modifier, the shading on the left eye disappears too.

How do i make the shading apply on the both eyes?
Here is what ive done in shading.

[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: does the texture appear on the backside of the right eyeball? if so, maybe apply rotation.... (just a guess...)

Comment: The shading does not appear at the back. To "solve" it, i created an eye and did the texture then duplicated the eye and this worked for me fortunately